# AAD B2C returned "AADB2C90090: The provided JWE is not a valid 5 segment token." when calling token API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am working a POC to verify the migration of our Signup & Signup flow to Azure AD B2C. I have successfully called the API `authorize` to get the `access token` and `id token`. Then I tried to call `/token` to refresh the token according to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#request-a-token) , however I got the error message below.

> AADB2C90090: The provided JWE is not a valid 5 segment token.\r\nCorrelation ID: ae943eb7-9290-4fd5-aeac-d56411d803c7\r\nTimestamp: 2022-10-26 07:13:40Z\r\n

Following is the URL I used to get access token in the browser.

```
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_signupsignin1&client_id=7adbb5f8-17d2-4dfa-94cd-5ab1cbc9f425&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid offline_access&response_type=code+id_token&prompt=login
```

Following is the screenshot I used to call token API in Postman.

```
POST /{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin1/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: {tenant}.b2clogin.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 1971

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=7adbb5f8-17d2-4dfa-94cd-5ab1cbc9f425&code=eyJraWQiOiJjcGltY29yZV8wOTI1MjAxNSIsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsInppcCI6IkRlZmxhdGUiLCJzZXIiOiIxLjAifQ..n8murSwIYYseViQm.WluJ_gU8aUQd1PPadPik4ODSso4KpKAu8geA5NmAlkbieJPVZb30MJSHGOiUsrxfwu4BoV69bshD7URJeVNFzfqPsCjBhpYDyeL8x0uUZIJwDQ7DTiflw8A4LbYf-SzjluqbfSqDwQFGyQvKesgsrnZzyxg9AnLiL1NoBW27Kd3ZcX3i1BHKr8c--qOyxbz8DtUyIzkJGcOq79wIQZRnDCr1_xPo6EhzOi59TlEIfJhzR4qfgLm3tlgK8zDaUY5Zf3a89olfkmpvrjS84vsfDyyWM4UZe_6MpymNQFe-6Q-fJRmWqdmqdvljaDykP2ZSZJS6jHkdmU9t9aYCTWPB4JgnN1PleQDzRK-MR9WPJ5ULoxmp2VOZ_YFdY94MOGEW8c_IeNGVuPRRC8jXEaQnEWA_3Fs5tzuNe4UjQUxRTTjNeZERb1MHFPk2YGZRc4CshvqvobuGQ2fVNKFHA8JvW9Qt6Xibw0gfY8D0tTZuOP6IxPwhFSWXa5nX4j_lDeFFxhTKA38CALXQ1FVWvHZmzYhB_yMYq44jdG46lpQYB4rV9CFIBvFzJ940EPH6LpOPAnLQzLNm6zqtsVKUoB49dXE2hapIbD5LHsoNoZYeQhu8qJdhxg.8PfqgqgrubNchCs9OxHQQA%26id_token%3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.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.RckgULrCBdXzw-7-VYgmB7k0Ghfg1jRMsJF8_1oxLbNXTOcZDe9grbJKcpWoesHp5L5_bVfAa1HQOFzMlmPwPPvM0a2yl1zT8UQzJ_a8W4EHkA4Ao3Xt3osbjoBhRh65Nu4fCVGHswPgxZNAR_N7jr4pR6Pf4PllmKpne-bw7onz_HjpT4ulyyq8jNZye3YokPZh0ha9LaV_19NiwfnVAR451lqfugKs2DWfseXbyGlOnjFCl_UHQDOxa1_ZUTmvF1JUgff2VAOmW2925RMQopzfDjCUEvwZMLr8pKTystErvUR6a8itRAKIFwbfEh3en8PqBun9T89-5qKmmN4NTQ&client_secret=h888Q~Jlg97L2ngl6GHpaKqS6FmkLygeTVY7Eb-h
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

To generate the **access token, ID token and code in the browser** I used the below parameters:

```json
GET https://Tenant.b2clogin.com/Tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testuserflow/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=37cd7fca-ea8f-4300-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
&response_type=code+id_token
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=openid
&state=12345
```

[image]

The error usually occurs if you pass **invalid code** value. To resolve the error, make sure to copy only the **`code`** value not with id token.

[image]

I am able to call `/token` to refresh the token successfully like below:

[image]